# One of Ubuntu Server folders is down?

Tags: server, apt, updates

Here are a simple link on archive.ubuntu.com to folder with folders starts with letter A.
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/

Many folders in archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/ are accessible.

BUT I FOUND THAT FOLDER NOT accessible
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aufs-tools/

And this so called aufs-tools is dependency for docker-engine. So i can't install docker-engine with apt-get install docker-engine.

Could'n you please tell me why this shit not accessible?

Comment: I can access it. Maybe it was for maintainance?

Comment: I can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now.  Might've been in the middle of a sync or such with the other servers.

This is not able to be replicated though; nor should you be trying to dig into those folders yourself unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes I check with other internet connection. Sorry for waste of time.